# Firebase on child_added watch for the grand children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
foo:{
    'uid1':{
        'push1':'bar1'
        'push1':'bar1'
        'push1':'bar1' // watch for child added here
    },
    'uid2':{
        'push1':'bar1'
        'push1':'bar1'
        'push1':'bar1' // watch for child added here
    },
}
```

Given the schema above, how do I get new `child_added` under the `uid1` or `uid2` while watching for `foo`?

```
dbRef.child('foo')
    .on('child_added', snap => {
        console.log(snap.key);
        console.log(snap.val());
    });
```

I have this query above, but it only fires when the new data is added directly under `foo` but not when the data is added to `foo`'s children.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to wire up another listener for the children:

```
dbRef.child('foo')
    .on('child_added', snap => {
        console.log(snap.key);
        console.log(snap.val());
        dbRef.child('foo').child(snap.key)
            .on('child_added', snap => {
                console.log(snap.key);
                console.log(snap.val());
            });
    });
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks @Mathew Berg